# Configuration issue in azure api management service

Tags: api, azure-api-management, apim

[image]

IN APIM I am facing this issue.I tried multiple time but still it shows not found.

I already created logicapp with my name and trying to configure it from APIM . Checking it in API's logicapp resource.

Comment: the error generally occurs when your logic App don't have appropriate access to configure and apim regions are different from logic App. it would be great if you provide details of your apim and logic App.

Comment: My apim region: Central US; resource group: integrationrg; logic app resource group: integrationrg; region: East US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error generally occurs when your logic App don't have appropriate access to configure and your APIM regions are different from logic App.

**Issue reproduced from my end getting same error when my logic App and APIM are in different locations.**

- Created my APIM in west US region as shown in below image
  [image]
- Then i created floatlp logic App under central US region and then in APIM i try to add this in under API's . As shown in image my logic App and APIM are at different regions it shows NO results found as expected.
  [image]
  [image]
- Then again i created explap01 in the West US region as APIM region and then i can see my logicapp in APIM API's search results.
  [image]
  [image]
  **Note**: My subscription and resource group also same for my APIM and logicapp.
- So, you're facing this issue because of region if possible try in same region. It avoids performance, configuration, latency and networking issues. If you want it in different regions refer below document, it may helps.

Refer this MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-logic-app-as-api) import a logic App which supports multi-tenant Logic Apps environment.